# How can I select an XPath with multiple conditions

Tags: css, xml, selenium, xpath

From this website, I want to get all genres in the Genres & Subgenres menu using the selenium framework. For that, I need a general xpath or css selector that applies to all of them. I have noticed that all genres have "genreid:D+++" as a part of their id and are located in  tag. How can I use this information to get all genres? If you know a better way to solve my problem please write it.

https://www.allmovie.com/advanced-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more familiar with CSS than XPath so I will answer that part of your question.

To make a CSS selection for an element ID that *starts with* genreid, you'd use this selector:

```css
[id^=genreid]
```

That will give you the checkboxes. If you wanted the `<li>` elements that contain them, you could just select by the classname: `.genre`

For more info about CSS selection, see MDN's great documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 1):

Xpath for all Genres & Subgenres

```
//input[contains(@id,'genreid')]
```